# document.getElementById from element

Tags: javascript, image, html

I'm trying to have a `div` change the `src` of another image on roll over, but I get a `TypeError: 'null' is not an object.`

```
<div id="text" onmouseover="document.getElementById('button').src='pushed.png'">
Hello
</div>
<img id"button" src="unpushed.png"/>
```

Comment: do you mean `id="button"`

Comment: You're missing an = on the img id attribute.

Comment: Why is mouse over on a different element the same as pushing a button?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is because you're midding the `=` in `id"button"`.